# lexical error: invalid bytes in UTF8 string

Tags: r, jsonlite

I am trying to use the code shown below to extract data from a json file. 
However, the following error is returned:

```
Error: lexical error: invalid bytes in UTF8 string.
          fr":"Ces donnÃ©es sont publiées avec un dÃ©lai de cinq jours
                     (right here) ------^
```

Inspecting the json file in my browser shows that the data appears as such:

```
"fr":"Ces donn\u00e9es sont publi�es avec un d\u00e9lai de cinq jours."
```

Is there a way to write the data while ignoring any UTF8 strings that cause an error?

```
library(jsonlite)

URL <- paste0("https://www.energy-charts.de/power_unit/month_lignite_unit_2017_12.json")

data <- fromJSON(getURL(URL))
```

Comment: The errors you are seeing are caused by having non-UTF-8 strings being declared to be UTF-8.  The solution is to declare them properly from the beginning; then the errors will go away.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the URL returns data in a `latin1` encoding, and your system is defaulting to reading it as UTF-8.  You can get it correctly using

```
library(jsonlite)
library(RCurl)  

URL <- "https://www.energy-charts.de/power_unit/month_lignite_unit_2017_12.json"

data <- fromJSON(getURL(URL, encoding = "latin1"))
```

I've also corrected some minor errors in your code:  you forgot to request `RCurl`, and `paste0` was not needed.

Comment: jsonlite can extract data from a URL automatically, using the curl package (which is by the same author)

Comment: Sure, but it doesn't work in this case, because the server isn't declaring the encoding of the file.  If you're on a system which defaults to UTF-8, you'll get the error the OP got.